# Custom Functor instance: Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘AST’ has kind ‘*’

Tags: haskell, functor, abstract-data-type

I have this rather simple ADT:

```
data AST = Node String [AST]
     | Leaf String
     | Empty
    deriving (Show)
```

and this Functor instance:

```
instance Functor AST where
    fmap f (Node s l) = Node (f s) (fmap f l)
    fmap f (Leaf s)   = Leaf (f s)
    fmap f Empty      = Empty
```

But when I try to compile it I get this error that I absolutely not understand:

```
Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘AST’ has kind ‘*’
   • In the first argument of ‘Functor’, namely ‘AST’
     In the instance declaration for ‘Functor AST’
```

Does anyone know why this happens? I can't find a solution in the Internet.

Comment: As a sanity check, does this instance `fmap` actually do anything? `Functor` instances contain things that one can "map" over but there's no data such mappable data in your AST.

Comment: The categorically minded should note that the `AST` and `fmap` definitions here constitute a perfectly sensible categorical functor, even if they do not make a valid Haskell `Functor`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A functor works on *type constructors*: if you give it an `AST`, it expects to see a:

```
data AST a = ...
--       ^ type parameter
```

We can also see this in the *definition* of the `Functor` class:

```
class Functor (f :: * -> *) where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Notice that the `f` in the head of the class has "*kind*" `* -> *` this means that acts as some sort of function that takes another type (the first `*`) and produces a type (the second `*`). As you can see `fmap` will take a function of type `a -> b` (where we have not much control over what `b` is). In your definition of `fmap`, we could only provide a `String -> String` function.

Right now it does not make much sense to make `AST` a functor, since it is not a functor.

You can however easily *generalize* your `AST` into:

```
data AST a = Node a [AST a]
     | Leaf a
     | Empty
    deriving (Show)
```

If you work with that type, an `AST String` is equivalent to your old definition for an `AST`.

The same holds for a list `[]` (which is a `Functor` as well). A *pseudo*-definition of a list is:

```
data [] a = [] | a : [a]
```

We define `Functor` over a list as:

```
instance Functor [] where
    fmap _ [] = []
    fmap f (x:xs) = (f x) : (fmap f xs)
```

Mind that we did *not* state `Functor [a]`, but `Functor []`.

Comment: Minor point: I wonder if "higher order type" is the right term here. I'd never met that before, I think, and I would associate it to something like `(*->*)->*`, similarly to higher-order functions. A `*->*` type for be is a parametric type, parametrized type, or (in the right context) type family, type function.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know Functor has to be polymorphic. For my code I am only interested in the String version, so I left it out

Answer (score 2):

Functors are required to be polymorphic, ie `data AST a = ...`. This is what "kind" means in this case. It wants `AST` not to be a type, but a type function, taking a type and returning a type.