# Haskell Error: Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘Movie’ has kind ‘*’

Tags: haskell, functor, algebraic-data-types

I created a "Movie" algebraic data type (as requested by the task):

```
data Movie = Movie { title :: String, director :: String, releaseYear :: Int}
```

Then added a functor:

```
instance Functor Movie where
    fmap _ Nothing = Nothing 
    fmap f (Movie title director releaseYear) = Movie (f title) (f director) (f releaseYear)
```

After that I wrote several functions to test the program's operation:

```
appendYear :: String -> String
appendYear title = title ++ " (2023)"

sampleMovie :: Movie
sampleMovie = Movie "Cool Film" "Amazing Director" 2000

modifiedMovie :: Movie
modifiedMovie = fmap appendYear sampleMovie
```

And after I try to call functions...

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    print sampleMovie
    print modifiedMovie
```

...I have the following:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, main.o )
main.hs:3:18: error:
    • Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘Movie’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the first argument of ‘Functor’, namely ‘Movie’
      In the instance declaration for ‘Functor Movie’
  |
3 | instance Functor Movie where
  |                  ^^^^^
```

Please help me figure out the problem. I have only recently started studying Haskell, so I use an online compiler

Tried to do something like this on other task:

```
data Possibly a = NotThere
                | There a 
                deriving (Show, Functor)
```

```
instance Functor Possibly where
    fmap _ NotThere = NotThere
    fmap f (There a) = There (f a)
```

...but it didn't lead me to anything.

Comment: Movie cannot be a functor. Only a type constructor with one argument can be a functor. Movie has zero arguments. Why do you think it should be a functor?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Functor instance: Expected kind ‘\* -> \*’, but ‘AST’ has kind ‘\*’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45235808/custom-functor-instance-expected-kind-but-ast-has-kind)

Comment: @cafce25 Partially yes, but I had problems with labels. In many ways, I did what was prescribed in the study materials, so I wanted to get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here: first of all the:

```
fmap _ Nothing = Nothing
```

makes no sense: `Nothing` is a data constructor of the `Maybe` type, not of the `Movie` type.

But the most important one is that the `Functor` works on a parameterized type: this allows to change the type. This thus means that the `Movie` should be defined like:

```
data Movie a = Movie { title :: a, director :: String, releaseYear :: Int}

instance Functor Movie where
    fmap f m(Movie {title=t}) = m { … }
```

where I leave implementing the `…` part as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got confused about several labels and how it was described in the training materials.